# PXE dhcp route issue

Tags: centos, dhcp

I have PXE running on Centos 6.x. I am trying to image a server with 4 nics. eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3.

eth0 and eth1 are on the network segment that the pxe server is on. I also using this pxe server to serve up files required for the build process via a webserver.

When DHCP hands out an IP address, it does so for all the interfaces, eth0 eth1 eth2 and eth3. It also hands out a default gateway. The default gateway gets configured on eth3. This is wrong as eth3 is not connected to the network where the web server is and it cannot pull down it's files from the webserver.

the address range I am using in PXE is 192.168.20.0/24 gw 192.168.20.1. How can I get PXE DHCP to set the default gateway 192.168.20.1 on eth0 and not eth3

here is the route table

```
Destination     Gateway      Genmask         Flags   Metric  Ref  Use   IFace

192.168.20.0    *            255.255.255.0   U       0       0    0     eth3
192.168.20.0    *            255.255.255.0   U       0       0    0     eth2
192.168.20.0    *            255.255.255.0   U       0       0    0     eth1
192.168.20.0    *            255.255.255.0   U       0       0    0     eth0
127.0.0.1       *            255.255.255.0   U       0       0    0     lo  
default         192.168.20.1 0.0.0.0         UG      0       0    0     eth3
```

here is my dhcp config

```
ddns-update-style interim;
not authoritative;

option domain-name "mydomain.com";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.20.15;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
subnet 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
authoritative;
range 192.168.20.220 192.168.20.245;
option routers 192.168.20.1;
default-lease-time 900;
max-lease-time 1200000000;

allow unknown-clients;
allow booting;
allow bootp;
next-server 192.168.20.15;
filename "pxelinux.0";
}
```

Any ideas how I get the default gateway to be on eth0 so I can route properly?

Thanks - Oli

Answer (score 0):

You said on question:

> server with 4 nics. eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3. ...
>   eth0 and eth1 are on the network segment that the pxe server is on. ...

then on the answer:

> another DHCP server that was issuing DHCP leases on the network that eth2 and eth3

So basically both segments DHCP servers provide same GW IP. It means that all your NIC's are on the same IP subnet `192.168.20.0/24`.

Change your subnet setup.

Answer (score -1):

I had another DHCP server that was issuing DHCP leases on the network that eth2 and eth3 was connected to. This interfered with the routes and caused eth0 and eth1 routing problems. I stopped the DHCP service on the network eth 2 and eth3 were on and everything was fine after that